# Initializing a Date property in beforeInsert fails without exception

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I have a standard user class, which has been created by the spring-security-core plugin in Grails 2.0.1. I use mongodb for persistence using the mongodb plugin.

If I add a Date property to the user class and change the beforeInsert() event handler to something like this

```
def beforeInsert() {
    userCreated = new Date()
    encodePassword()
}
```

the user no longer is persisted. There is no exception shown. It just silently fails.
If I initialize the userCreated property when it is defined:

```
Date userCreated = new Date()
```

and remove the initialization from the beforeInsert() event handler everything works fine.
Does anyone have an explanation for that behaviour?

BTW: I intentionally do not use the automatic timestamping feature, since I want to use the date of creation to salt passwords. If I use dateCreated via automatic timestamping, the dateCreated field is updated after the beforeInsert() event handler is called and the passwords no longer work.

Comment: Try adding grails.gorm.failOnError  to Config.groovy and running your code again. This should show an exception if there any problem with model.

Comment: added the line grails.gorm.failOnError = true to conf/Config.groovy, but nothing changed... still silently failing...

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap beforeInsert code into transaction because encodePassword() method is not a service method as i suppose

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Is this what you are talking about? Adding an Annotation to the method?  @Transactional
 def beforeInsert() {
  created = new Date()
  encodePassword()
 }

Comment: Or did you mean using something like this:  def beforeInsert() {
  User.withTransaction{
   created = new Date()
   encodePassword()
  }
 } However, did not have any luck... still the same problem. encodePassword() is not a service. Just a helper method in the domain class.

Comment: i meant as your last comment. so.. In beforeInsert i used withNewSession {session-> ... } in my own project. May be it will help you...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. My beforeInsert callback now looks like this:  def beforeInsert() {
  User.withNewSession { session ->
  created = new Date()
  encodePassword()
  }
 }   However, it still fails silently... There are no users in the DB as long as I have the created = new Date() line in my event listener. Everything works fine if I remove this line. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Strange... try to rename 'userCreated' to smth like 'userDateCreation'.

Comment: hmm, I already renamed it from "dateCreated" with autotimestamp disabled to "userCreated" to "created" as I suspected a problem with the naming. However, the behavior didn't change a bit. This leaves me completely puzzled at the moment, as the grails documentation shows a similar implementation when explaining the autotimestamp feature http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping